# Grouping lists in Python but keeping them in order

Tags: python

Say I have the following list:

```
list1 = [{'position':'child','title':'dave','obj':obj,created:'2013-11-20'},
         {'position':'child','title':'james','obj':obj,created:'2013-11-19'},
         {'position':'child','title':'james','obj':obj,created:'2013-11-18'},
         {'position':'child','title':'ian','obj':obj,created:'2013-11-17'},
         {'position':'child','title':'dave','obj':obj,created:'2013-11-16'},
         {'position':'child','title':'dave','obj':obj,created:'2013-11-15'},
         {'position':'child','title':'dave','obj':obj,created:'2013-11-14'}]
```

As you can see it is already in date order (and I want to keep it that way). There are lots of answers on stackoverflow on how to use `defaultdict` to group by common entries, but is there a way to group by `title` while preserving the `created` order, like so:

```
list1 = [{'position':'parent','title':'dave root'},
         {'position':'child','title':'dave','obj':obj,created:'2013-11-20'},
         {'position':'parent','title':'james root'},
         {'position':'child','title':'james','obj':obj,created:'2013-11-19'},
         {'position':'child','title':'james','obj':obj,created:'2013-11-18'},
         {'position':'parent','title':'ian root'},
         {'position':'child','title':'ian','obj':obj,created:'2013-11-17'},
         {'position':'parent','title':'dave root'},
         {'position':'child','title':'dave','obj':obj,created:'2013-11-16'},
         {'position':'child','title':'dave','obj':obj,created:'2013-11-15'},
         {'position':'child','title':'dave','obj':obj,created:'2013-11-14'}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
list1 = [{'position':'child','title':'dave','obj':'obj','created':'2013-11-20'},
         {'position':'child','title':'james','obj':'obj','created':'2013-11-19'},
         {'position':'child','title':'james','obj':'obj','created':'2013-11-18'},
         {'position':'child','title':'ian','obj':'obj','created':'2013-11-17'},
         {'position':'child','title':'dave','obj':'obj','created':'2013-11-16'},
         {'position':'child','title':'dave','obj':'obj','created':'2013-11-15'},
         {'position':'child','title':'dave','obj':'obj','created':'2013-11-14'}]

import itertools
import operator

list1 = [
    x
    for key, grp in itertools.groupby(list1, key=operator.itemgetter('title'))
    for x in [{'position': 'parent', 'title': key + ' root'}]+ list(grp)
]
for x in list1:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
{'position': 'parent', 'title': 'dave root'}
{'position': 'child', 'created': '2013-11-20', 'obj': 'obj', 'title': 'dave'}
{'position': 'parent', 'title': 'james root'}
{'position': 'child', 'created': '2013-11-19', 'obj': 'obj', 'title': 'james'}
{'position': 'child', 'created': '2013-11-18', 'obj': 'obj', 'title': 'james'}
{'position': 'parent', 'title': 'ian root'}
{'position': 'child', 'created': '2013-11-17', 'obj': 'obj', 'title': 'ian'}
{'position': 'parent', 'title': 'dave root'}
{'position': 'child', 'created': '2013-11-16', 'obj': 'obj', 'title': 'dave'}
{'position': 'child', 'created': '2013-11-15', 'obj': 'obj', 'title': 'dave'}
{'position': 'child', 'created': '2013-11-14', 'obj': 'obj', 'title': 'dave'}
```

Comment: can you explain `for key, grp in itertools.groupby(list1, key=operator.itemgetter('title'))` and `for x in [...]+ list(grp)` for me. Also what is `x` doing? Why is it there?

Comment: @Sevenearths, `operator.itemgetter('title')` is like `lambda x: x['title']`. See http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter

Comment: @Sevenearths, `x` is element of [...] + list(grp). See [List comphrension - from Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).